# How to set a minimum width in a responsive Gridview in asp.net while using ControlStyle

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, responsive

I have a gridview with a custom css that makes it somewhat of a responsive table so the table columns shrink when the screen is reduced in size.

The problem I have is when shrinking the screen I don't want the columns to reduce so far that you can't see them anymore and would like a minimum-width added to each field.

The issue is specifically when I am using "ControlStyle". When this is set to 100% it seems to disregard my min-width setting.

I am new to this so excuse me if this is a simple problem.

**Here is my gridview:**

```
               <asp:GridView 
                    ID="GridView1" 
                    runat="server" 
                    AllowPaging="True" 
                    OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting"
                    OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" 
                    borderwidth="0" 
                    OnSorting="TaskGridView_Sorting" 
                    GridLines="None"
                    CssClass="mGrid"
                    PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
                    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                    AllowSorting="True" 
                    PageSize="<%# Convert.ToInt32(ddlPage.Text) %>" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    CellPadding="0">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="name" HeaderText="Name">                
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="name" CssClass="mlm2" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' width="125" OnTextChanged="text_change" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle width="125" />                                
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="phone" HeaderText="Phone">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="phone" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="mlm2" runat="server" width="75" Text='<%# Eval("phone") %>' 
                                OnTextChanged="text_change" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ControlStyle Width="100%" />                               
                        </asp:TemplateField>    
                     </Columns>
               </asp:GridView>
```

**Here is the custom CSS:**

```
.mGrid { 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #fff; 
    margin: 5px 0 10px 0; 
    border: solid 1px #525252; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
}
.mGrid td { 
    padding: 2px; 
    border: solid 1px #c1c1c1; 
    color: #717171; 
}
.mGrid th { 
    padding: 4px 2px; 
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff; 
    background: #e0ebeb url(grd_head.png) repeat-x top; 
    border-left: solid 1px #525252; 
    font-size: 0.9em; 
}
```

Comment: how about `min-width`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width

Comment: This did not resolve my issue. When I use ControlStyle Width="100%" and min-width=75 the column still shrinks below 75px when controlstyle width is set to 100%. I want to keep using controlstyle width at 100% as I like the responsiveness when its larger than the minimum size I want. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: What CSS/script does ControlStyleWidth get turned into? I haven't got an ASP.NET Forms app handy to check what it does. Also are you setting that on the GridView, or a sub-part of it? And did you set min-width in both the `.mgrid td` and `.mgrid th` rules in your CSS? BTW you have to specify the units and use `:` not `=` so it should be `min-width: 75px`